# Class / Instance type checking rules learning resources

Tags: haskell, typechecking

Currently, I'm trying to understand more about [Instance termination rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#class-and-instances-declarations), in order to explain errors like `The constraint ... is no smaller than the instance head`, and not to use `UndecidableInstances` without exactly knowing that it does.

I'm sure there are more rules of the type checker regarding instances that I don't know about and that I would be interested to learn.

Where could I find a more detailed description of what Haskell does there?
Unfortunately, [Understanding Functional Dependencies via
Constraint Handling Rules](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/jfp06.pdf) seems a little too much (complex) for me.

Comment: What makes you so sure that the GHC documentation is incomplete?

Comment: @DanielW Sorry. I did not say that. Java lang spec is complete, but it's not a very good place for e beginner to start. I know, it's an exaggerated comparison.

Comment: Hey, asking for offsite resources is OT on SO (lots of reasons, for example offsite resources tend to become available or get out of date)

Comment: Do you perhaps have a specific question about `10.8.3.4. Instance termination rules` (scrolling down from your first link)? Those rules look pretty clear to me...

Comment: @Cubic It's just hard to understand from only one information source... even "smaller than" is not exactly clear for me...